# Coxph "X matrix deemed to be singular" without perfect classification?

Tags: r, cox-regression

I am trying to carry out a self-controlled case series using the package `sccs` from [here](http://statistics.open.ac.uk/sccs/r.htm).  This is a statistical method which takes "baseline" and "exposed" periods in the timecourse of e.g. a year of a patient's life.  The exposed periods could represent exposure to a drug and the outcome measured could be a side-effect of the drug as, indeed, it is in my case.

This package essentially formats the data into intervals of baseline and exposure risk.  A patient identifier `indivL` (factor), `interval` (integer, number of days), `exposure` status (0/1), `event` status (0/1).  It then feeds this data into `survival::clogit` as a model of the form:

```
event ~ exposure + strata(indivL) + offset(log(interval))
```

The data fed to `clogit` is a data frame of the form:

```
   indivL event eventday  lower  upper interval age   exposure  indiv aevent astart   aend drugtype
 * <fct>  <dbl>    <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <fct> <fct>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 1         0.    22361 22219. 22252.      34. 1     0           1. 22361. 22219. 22460.        0.
 2 1         0.    22361 22253. 22260.       8. 1     1           1. 22361. 22219. 22460.        0.
 3 1         1.    22361 22261. 22460.     200. 1     0           1. 22361. 22219. 22460.        0.
 4 2         0.    22401 22219. 22252.      34. 1     0           1. 22401. 22219. 22460.        0.
 5 2         0.    22401 22253. 22260.       8. 1     1           1. 22401. 22219. 22460.        0.
 6 2         1.    22401 22261. 22460.     200. 1     0           1. 22401. 22219. 22460.        0.
 7 3         0.    31071 30834. 30863.      30. 1     0           2. 31071. 30834. 31075.        0.
 8 3         0.    31071 30864. 30871.       8. 1     1           2. 31071. 30834. 31075.        0.
 9 3         1.    31071 30872. 31075.     204. 1     0           2. 31071. 30834. 31075.        0.
10 4         1.      261   207.   356.     150. 1     0           3.   261.   207.   425.        0.
# ... with 1,211,460 more rows
```

I have my model working well for giving me a result when using the above.  However, I want to add in other independent variables.  These are binary categoricals and I have tried them as both 0/1 integers and 2-level factors.  One example would be `drugtype`.  In this case the model takes the form:

```
event ~ exposure + drugtype + strata(indivL) + offset(log(interval))
```

My error is:

```
Warning message:
In coxph(formula = Surv(rep(1, 176241L), event) ~ exposure + drugtype +  :
  X matrix deemed to be singular; variable 2
```

My model is:

```
--SNIP--
coxph(formula = Surv(rep(1, 176241L), event) ~ exposure + drugtype + 
     strata(indivL) + offset(log(interval)), data = chopdat, method = "exact")

  n= 176049, number of events= 58602 
   (192 observations deleted due to missingness)

             coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z            Pr(>|z|)    
exposure1 0.70760   2.02912  0.01662 42.57 <0.0000000000000002 ***
drugtype       NA        NA  0.00000    NA                  NA    
--SNIP--
```

As you can see, it does not like `drugtype`, which is a binary variable.

Having looked around I've come across several sources which suggest the problem is a case of "perfect classification" i.e. one of my variables perfectly predicts the presence of another.  However, using `xtabs()` I get:

```
> xtabs(~drugtype + event, data = chopdat)

         event
 drugtype      0      1
        0 778306 388279
        1  29344  14625
```

and

```
> xtabs(~ exposure + event, data = chopdat)

        event
exposure      0      1
       0 427482 380101
       1 380788  23113
```

and

```
> xtabs(~ drugtype + exposure, data = chopdat)

       drugtype
exposure      0      1
       0 777655  29308
       1 388930  14661
```

Suggesting there is a good distribution and no perfect classification.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for some more information on this?  I feel I've reached the limits of what I'm able to do with the documentation and searching for other answers to this question on StackOverflow.

Many thanks.

Comment: What about `drugtype` by `events`?

Comment: Thanks @Mike, I've updated the question with this `xtabs()`

Comment: what is the difference between the `dat` dataframe and `chopdat` dataframe, `chopdat` is used in the model and `dat` is used in the `xtabs`?

Comment: Sorry @Mike, an oversight on my part - they are the same dataframe.  I've changed the question accordingly.

Comment: There might be perfect separation when you include all of the other variables in the model, if you just run the model with drug type do you get that error?

Comment: @Mike: even running as `event ~ drugtype` gives me: `X matrix deemed to be singular; variable 1`

Comment: Without data I cannot really reproduce the error/be more helpful. Just from the snippet above I can see that `drugtype` only has values of 0 (I realize that you did not show the whole dataframe).  Also why are you specifying the time component as a vector of 1 to the length of your df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, hello all.

Many thanks to @Mike for trying to help me.  I have found the explanation for this behaviour and it is a quirk of the SCCS method of modelling rather than to do with `clogit` itself.

From Farrington, Whitaker and Weldeselassie *Self-Controlled Case Series Studies, A Modelling Guide with R*:

> Note that the main effect of the covariate is not included in the model formula, since it cannot be estimated in a SCCS model as it drops out of the likelihood.

So, the main effect cannot be estimate and is thus returned as `NA`.

Apologies for posting a question to which I should have been able to find an answer but hopefully this will be of use to anyone else who runs across this "problem".

Comment: Hi, I know the question is old but if anyone stumble on it 

You could still use that drugtype variable with an interaction or stratification, it's also mentionned in the guide but yes all time invarying confounders are automatically canceled